# How to describe a company that is disorganized?

Tags: word-requests

I'm looking for a word or phrase to describe a company that is organizationally disorganized. I am not sure if words that describe physically disorganized (like a messy desk for which you could say 散らかってる) would be appropriate for this case.

To be more specific, imagine a company whose customer support you call, and get forwarded to 5 or 6 different people before they finally answer your question. Would something like "まとまってない" apply here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I called their customer support and got forwarded to 5 or 6 different people, I'd say なってない ("not doing properly, decently"). What I mean is there are numerous situations when you utter "disorganized" regarding a company, and you have to choose different word in Japanese on each.

- ばらばら: "teared up", "disintegrated", "disunited"
- ぐちゃぐちゃ: "messy", "disturbed", "in a shambles"
- なっていない: (see above)
- まとまりがない: "not cohesive", "uncoordinated"
- 体をなしていない: "shapeless", "dysfunctional" (usually with a noun such as 会社の体をなしていない)
- でたらめ、めちゃくちゃ: "chaotic", "irresponsible"
- 無秩序: "disordered", "headless", "chaotic"
- 空中分解寸前: "is going to 'break up in midair'"

etc.

Comment: 「体をなす」って「ていをなす」って読みますよね？「たいをなす」とも言います？

Comment: @chocolate 何か調べたらどっちもあるみたいです。個人的には「ていをなす」で読んでます。

Comment: Is "なってない" slang? I've very rarely heard this expression used in this way. Does it derive from なる ("to become") or a completely different word?

Comment: @Locksleyu Yes it's from なる. It's not that slang-ish as I can also find a dictionary entry for this phrase: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/165425/meaning/m0u/ 「非常に悪くて問題にならない。」

Answer (score 2):

めちゃめちゃ (me-cha me-cha) means "messed-up".

> - あの会社の進め方はめちゃめちゃだね = That company way of doing things is messed-up (disorganized).
> - この部屋はめちゃめちゃだね = This room is really messy.

めちゃめちゃ has also, through slang, come to be used to mean "very" before an adjective, e.g.,

> - めちゃめちゃいい = very good
> - めちゃめちゃ大きい = very big.

But that is a different usage.

Comment: Can you explain why you used 進め方 here? What is being "proceeded"?

Comment: @Locksleyu 進め方 is more or less a [fixed word meaning "procedure".](http://jisho.org/search/%E9%80%B2%E3%82%81%E6%96%B9)

Comment: Is めっちゃ the same thing or is that a totally different word (for the 2nd meaning above)? I think it might have come from 関西弁